# unknown version in python library pyparsing

Tags: python, pyparsing

I am trying to install airnotifier on my machine, I am getting this error

My python version is 3.6

```
PS C:\airnotifier> python app.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 32, in <module>
    from pushservices.bootstrap import init_messaging_agents
  File "C:\airnotifier\pushservices\bootstrap.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .fcm import FCMClient
  File "C:\airnotifier\pushservices\fcm.py", line 5, in <module>
    from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
  File "C:\Users\smacrsadmin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\service_account.py", line 25, in <module>
    from oauth2client import client
  File "C:\Users\smacrsadmin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\client.py", line 39, in <module>
    from oauth2client import transport
  File "C:\Users\smacrsadmin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\transport.py", line 17, in <module>
    import httplib2
  File "C:\Users\smacrsadmin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\httplib2\__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
    from . import auth
  File "C:\Users\smacrsadmin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\httplib2\auth.py", line 4, in <module>
    import pyparsing as pp
  File "C:\Users\smacrsadmin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pyparsing\__init__.py", line 130, in <module>
    __version__ = __version_info__.__version__
AttributeError: 'version_info' object has no attribute '__version__'
```

Comment: You may have an old version of httplib2 - they recently released an upgrade to work with the latest pyparsing.

Comment: the problem in oauth2client as I think and I tried to install other versions and same error happen

Comment: Try manually installing pyparsing 2.4.7 using "pip install pyparsing==2.4.7". There are some versioning issues being sorted out, so using the last stable pyparsing version should be of some help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I received the same error and I'm also in Python 3.6.0 ...

```
AttributeError: 'version_info' object has no attribute '__version__'
```

If you want to dig a little more, you can type this in your console and detect which package is using this dependency.

```
> pip show pyparsing
```

In my case the output was something like this, indicating that **packaging**:

> - Name: pyparsing
> - Version: 2.4.7
> - Summary: Python parsing module
> - License: MIT License
> - Location:
> - Requires:
> - Required-by: packaging

To fix it, you can go with the suggestion from *PaulMcG*

```
pip install pyparsing==2.4.7
```

---

**Update 2022-Jun-03:**

Reference to the issue

https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing/releases/tag/pyparsing_3.0.8

Note says:

> API CHANGE: modified pyproject.toml to require Python version 3.6.8 or
> later for pyparsing 3.x. Earlier minor versions of 3.6 fail in
> evaluating the version_info class (implemented using
> typing.NamedTuple). If you are using an earlier version of Python 3.6,
> you will need to use pyparsing 2.4.7.