# pycharm : error while importing matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am using pycharm for Python in `Windows 10`.

I have installed the package matplotlib.
I am using python `3.6` when i do import `matplotlib` there is no error.
However if i do matplotlib.pyplot as plt i am getting this following errors:

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Year4/เจคจบ/Project/ex/Image_manipulation_detection-master/demo_two_stream.py", line 9, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 110, in <module>
    from matplotlib.rcsetup import validate_backend, cycler
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\rcsetup.py", line 28, in <module>
    from matplotlib.fontconfig_pattern import parse_fontconfig_pattern
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\fontconfig_pattern.py", line 15, in <module>
    from pyparsing import (Literal, ZeroOrMore, Optional, Regex, StringEnd,
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pyparsing\__init__.py", line 130, in <module>
    __version__ = __version_info__.__version__
AttributeError: 'version_info' object has no attribute '__version__'
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69964466/unknown-version-in-python-library-pyparsing

Comment: As you can tell from the error messages, the problem is not with `matplotlib`, but with `pyparsing`. Merely installing both `matplotlib` and `pyparsing` on Windows 10 64-bit on Python 3.6 and then executing `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` does not reproduce your error. Please share the code that actually reproduces your problem and mention what versions of the two packages you have installed (`pip list` or similar)

Comment: i install matplotlib 3.5.0 and pyparsing 3.0.4