# Matplotlib - AttributeError: 'version_info' object has no attribute '__version__"

Tags: python, matplotlib, attributeerror

I am not sure how to fix this error. I have tried searching everywhere. This error only comes up when I try to interact with matplotlib. My pip is fully upgraded and I am using python 3.6.0 for a class. Thank you!

Python 3.6.0 (v3.6.0:41df79263a11, Dec 23 2016, 07:18:10) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

> > > import matplotlib
> > > Traceback (most recent call last):
> > > File "", line 1, in 
> > > File "C:\Users\syner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib_*init*_.py", line 107, in 
> > > from . import cbook, rcsetup
> > > File "C:\Users\syner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\rcsetup.py", line 28, in 
> > > from matplotlib.fontconfig_pattern import parse_fontconfig_pattern
> > > File "C:\Users\syner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\fontconfig_pattern.py", line 15, in 
> > > from pyparsing import (Literal, ZeroOrMore, Optional, Regex, StringEnd,
> > > File "C:\Users\syner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pyparsing_*init*_.py", line 130, in 
> > > **version** = **version_info**.**version**
> > > AttributeError: 'version_info' object has no attribute '**version**'

Comment: Try this:`import matplotlib;print('matplotlib: {}'.format(matplotlib.__version__))`

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It still gives the same error and does not print a version.

Comment: However, when I run 'pip show matplotlib' in the cmd window, it shows 3.3.4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured out the solution for my problem. I noticed that just before the AttributeError, it is trying to import pyparsing, so I looked for solutions for that. I stumbled upon a stackoverflow post: [unknown version in python library pyparsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69964466/unknown-version-in-python-library-pyparsing)

The answer of installing version 2.4.7 worked for me. Since I am running 2016 software in 2021, I think the newest version was creating problems.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I found answer for my problem, before that I installed matplotlib for 3.6 then while importing tensorflow also its showing same issue after uninstalles matplotlib then tensorflow working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found this solution

[unknown version in python library pyparsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69964466/unknown-version-in-python-library-pyparsing?newreg=d4d630e2b0f943d5b7209e4f048853c2)

It is not Matplotlib that is the problem. It is pyparsing

"Try manually installing pyparsing 2.4.7 using "pip install pyparsing==2.4.7". There are some versioning issues being sorted out, so using the last stable pyparsing version should be of some help."

I installed this pyparsing version and now import matplotlib works.