# AttributeError: 'version_info' object has no attribute '__version__' when trying to load Yolo Model Weights

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, yolo

I am trying to follow this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_UqmgHKdntU

I cloned the github repository, and then I downloaded the weight files. I also created a virtual environment with `python 3.6.0` (because Python 3.9.2 was giving error due to incomaptibility with Tensorflow version 2.2 which was in the `requirements.txt` file)

However, when I tried to load the weights with the following command,

```
python load_weights.py
```

I am getting this error,

```
__version__ = __version_info__.__version__
AttributeError: 'version_info' object has no attribute '__version__'
```

I tried to find this a lot on Stackoverflow and other places on Google but could not find anything that worked for me.

The complete error is given below,

```
File "load_weights.py", line 4, in <module>
    from yolov3_tf2.models import YoloV3, YoloV3Tiny

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "load_weights.py", line 4, in <module>
    from yolov3_tf2.models import YoloV3, YoloV3Tiny
  File "E:\Example4\Object-Detection-API\yolov3_tf2\models.py", line 23, in <module>
    from .utils import broadcast_iou
  File "E:\Example4\Object-Detection-API\yolov3_tf2\utils.py", line 5, in <module>
    from seaborn import color_palette
  File "E:\Example4\Object-Detection-API\venv\lib\site-packages\seaborn\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .rcmod import *  # noqa: F401,F403
  File "E:\Example4\Object-Detection-API\venv\lib\site-packages\seaborn\rcmod.py", line 5, in <module>
    import matplotlib as mpl
  File "E:\Example4\Object-Detection-API\venv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 107, in <module>
    from . import cbook, rcsetup
  File "E:\Example4\Object-Detection-API\venv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\rcsetup.py", line 28, in <module>
    from matplotlib.fontconfig_pattern import parse_fontconfig_pattern
  File "E:\Example4\Object-Detection-API\venv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\fontconfig_pattern.py", line 15, in <module>
    from pyparsing import (Literal, ZeroOrMore, Optional, Regex, StringEnd,
  File "E:\Example4\Object-Detection-API\venv\lib\site-packages\pyparsing\__init__.py", line 130, in <module>
    __version__ = __version_info__.__version__
AttributeError: 'version_info' object has no attribute '__version__'
```

One of the solutions on Stackoverflow told me to change `pyparsing` library, [unknown version in python library pyparsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69964466/unknown-version-in-python-library-pyparsing)

**Edit:** I checked the pyparsing version using the command `pip show pyparsing`, which displayed the following results,

```
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ensorflow (e:\hassan\example4\object-detection-api\venv\lib\site-packages)
Name: pyparsing
Version: 3.0.7
Summary: Python parsing module
Home-page: https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing/
Author: Paul McGuire
Author-email: ptmcg.gm+pyparsing@gmail.com
License: MIT License
Location: e:\example4\object-detection-api\venv\lib\site-packages
Requires:
Required-by: matplotlib
```

After which I tried to install the pyparsing version `3.0.7` using the command `pip install pyparsing==3.0.7`, however I got this message,

```
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing==3.0.7 in e:\example4\object-detection-api\venv\lib\site-packages (3.0.7)
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.3.1; however, version 22.0.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'E:\Example4\Object-Detection-API\venv\Scripts\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

*I also tried to uninstall the pyparsing and again install the specified version, but the problem still persisted.*

Another solution asked me to also install the `tensorflow-gpu` which was given on the Github repository,

```
pip install -r requirements-gpu.txt
```

I tried this however this also did not work. I also tried to uninstall and install Tensorflow again, but again the same error persisted.

I also tried to upgrade my pip by using this,

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

This showed me the message that,

```
Requirement already satisfied: pip in e:\hassan\semester 8\research\example4\object-detection-api\venv\lib\site-packages (21.3.1)
```

However, at the end, it said that new version is still available (but it wouldn't install it, I don't know for what reason)

```
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.3.1; however, version 22.0.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'E:\Example4\Object-Detection-API\venv\Scripts\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

According to one of the posts, upgrading pip solves the problem. I tried to upgrade but it neither upgraded the pip version nor did it solve my problem.

Can anyone help me solve this `version` error?

Comment: "One of the solutions on Stackoverflow told me to change pyparsing library, unknown version in python library pyparsing" This is the correct solution, and if it didn't work for you, it's because something went wrong with your attempt. The most common problem is trying to install to a different Python than the one being used to run the code. Please keep in mind that this is not a discussion forum or tech support, and you are supposed to ask only one question at a time.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I followed everything given in that post (which was only two lines of code). I even uninstalled and then installed the pyparsing again (version `3.0.7` as per the packaging of pyparsing) however it still did not work for me. I am sure I did everything correctly (can't do much wrong on two lines of code)

Comment: You would need to show us exactly what you typed into the console in order to install `pyparsing`, exactly how you tried using the code after doing that, and exactly what happened as a result, in a new question. And even then, you would probably be better off trying https://superuser.com as the question is not actually about *writing code*.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I have modified my Question to include the lines I typed to install the pyparsing version. I believe I would ask it in the other platform however. Thank you.